# Textbox Auto Number generated in c# error

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a simple product form in c#. while I generated auto number getting error what I tried so far i attached below.product id starts with 00001. I created a method Getproduct() inside the method I wrote the code.error displayed syntax error.

```
public void Getproduct() {    
  string sql;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =.; initial catalog=product; integrated security=true");
  SqlDataAdapter dr;
  SqlDataReader dr1;
  sql = "SELECT id,product_name,product_desc,price FROM product Order By id Desc";
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
  SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
  if (dr.Read() == true) {
    int id;
    int pid;
    id = (dr[0] + 1);
    pid = id.ToString("00000");
    else if IsDBNull(dr) {
      pid = ("00001");

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Please fix curly brackets in the code near `else if IsDBNull(dr)` - it's something wrong there.

Comment: id = id = (dr[0] + 1); in this point what is the wrong

Comment: Please describe the problem you faced (a compiler error, a runtime error or something else) and include the error message, exception message+stack trace you got into the question.

Comment: .error displayed syntax error. id = (dr[0] + 1); at this point

Comment: What do you mean by `else`? Is it supposed to be related to `if (dr.Read() == true)`? If yes, add a closing `}` before `else` and remove excessive `}` at the end of the code block.

Comment: It is not an auto generated number if you are concocting it.  It is not your job to come up with a unique ID - let your DB do its job

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public void Getproduct()
    {
        string sql;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =.; initial catalog=product; integrated security=true");
        SqlDataAdapter dapt;
        SqlDataReader dr1;
        sql = "SELECT id,product_name,product_desc,price FROM product Order By id Desc";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        int id;
        string pid;

        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {

            int val = 0;

            Int32.TryParse(dr[0].ToString(),out val);

            id = ( val + 1);
            pid = id.ToString("00000");
        }
        else if( Convert.IsDBNull(dr) )
            {
                pid = ("00001");

            }

        }
```

Comment: id does not exist in the current context
pid does not exist in the current context   error displayed like that  id = ( val + 1);
            pid = id.ToString("00000");